# How to change directory? in PHP

Tags: php

when I worked with wamp, I had no problems, because I could have all of my files in same directory, but now I am using hosts server, so I have to change the path to the file I am working with, so PY files would work. `Hello.php` is in `/public_html/wp-content/plugins` and PY, that php is working with, is in `/public_html/cgi-bin`. This is hello.php code:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: hello */                    
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=cp1252');
add_shortcode( 'hello', 'execute_python_with_argv' );   
function execute_python_with_argv(){            
ob_start();
$description = array (     
0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
);
$application_system = "python ";
$application_path .= plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
$application_name .= "hello.py";                
$separator = " ";
$application = $application_system.$application_path.$application_name.$separator;
$pipes = array();
$proc = proc_open ( $application , $description , $pipes );
if (is_resource ( $proc ))
{
echo stream_get_contents ($pipes [1] ); //Reading stdout buffer
}
echo "soup";
$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
}
```

I have tried changing `$application_path .= plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );` to `$application_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; $application_path .= "/public_html/cgi-bin/hello.py";` didn't do anything. Any help would be appreciated, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Use [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) and [getcwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) functions.

**getcwd** — Gets the current working directory

**chdir** — Change directory

> Changes PHP's current directory to directory.

```
<?php

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";

chdir('cvs');

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";

?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
/home/didou
/home/didou/cvs
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I am in `cgi-bin` directory, now I have got some kind of error, `[28-Jun-2016 10:20:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/meteodat/public_html/wp-content/plugins/hello.php on line 18`

Comment: I don't know why this error is coming in your system but you can remove the proc_open string from the disable_functions at php.ini* file

Comment: My host said that php.ini is for all of their users and it cannot be changed, is there any other way?